Defining bitwise and in terms of bitwise masking
I need help completing a proof that defines bitwise-and in terms of arithmetic and bitwise-masking.
Let $\&$ denote the bitwise-and operation on natural numbers and $\preceq$ denote the bit-masking relation on natural numbers. Specifically, $x \preceq y$ if each binary digit of $x$ is $\leq$ the corresponding binary digit of $y$.
(3.6) of Jones and Matijasevic's "Proof of Recursive Unsolvability of Hilbert's Tenth Problem" states that bitwise-and can be expressed logically in terms of bit-masking: $$a \& b = c \text{ iff } c \preceq a \text{ and } a \preceq a+b-c.$$ This is the result I'd like a proof of, but unfortunately, the paper doesn't come with a proof of this, and internet searches are turning up basic computer-science introductions to bitwise operations.
I have the $\Rightarrow$ direction down. Let $a', b'$ be the digits of $a,b$ which are not common, then $a = a'+c$ and $b =b'+c$, so $$a+b-c = (a'+c)+(b'+c)-c = a'+b'+c = (a'+c)+b' = a+b'$$ $a+b'$ doesn't involve any carrying, so is $\succeq a$.
But I can't find a proof of $\Leftarrow$ that isn't incredibly tedious. Can anyone find a nice proof of this?
As a bonus, does anyone know of a reference that contains this result, that might contain other, similar results?

Perhaps you should edit your question and tell us something about your incredibly tedious proof, so we can help to improve it.

The reverse implication doesn't seem to hold. If $a, b, c$ are the single bits $1, 1, 0$ respectiviely, we have $a \& b \ne c$ but $c \preceq a$ and $a \preceq a+b-c$.
By the way, it appears (to me) that $a \preceq a+b-c$ can be simplified to $c \preceq b$.
